# Keras multiple output numpy transformation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a `y_train` dataset in the shape of `(samples, 9)`. My `X_train` input is in the shape of `(samples, 30, 1)`.

These run through a model constructed as:

```
def create_model(input_shape, outputs):
    i = Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = Dense(256, activation="relu")(i)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)

    # Optimize each binary output independently.
    o = list(map(lambda _: Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x), range(outputs)))

    m = Model(i, o)
    m.compile('adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return m

model = create_model((30, 1), 9)
```

Which produces a training error:

> Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you
>   are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected
>   to see 9 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:

```
[array([[1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   ...,
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0....
```

I've tried variations on the `y_train` shape, with `(9, samples, 1)` and `(samples, 1, 9)`. How does keras want to see my `(samples, 9)` array shape transformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model has 9 output layers, each with binary cross entropy. Therefore, you need to pass your outputs as a list of 9 outputs, where each output is a `(samples, 1)` sized array, not a single array with 9 columns.

Therefore, you need to do the following.

```
# Assuming your y_train is of size (samples, 9)
y_train_list = np.split(y_train, y_train.shape[1], axis=1)

model.fit(x_train, y_train_list)
```

Here's a working example with toy data

```
x_train = np.random.normal(size=(500,30,1))
y_train = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(500, 9))
y_train_list = np.split(y_train, y_train.shape[1], axis=1)
model.fit(X_tr, y_train_list)
```

### Using train_test_split to create train-validation data

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

tr_x, ts_x, tr_y, ts_y =train_test_split(X_tr, Y_tr, test_size=0.33)
tr_list_y = np.split(tr_y, tr_y.shape[1], axis=1)
ts_list_y = np.split(ts_y, ts_y.shape[1], axis=1)
model.fit(tr_x, tr_list_y, validation_data=(ts_x, ts_list_y))
```

Comment: With that, I'm getting an error: `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [samples, 9]`

Comment: Your `y_train` needs to be [samples, 9]. You might have passed a different sized `y_train`.

Comment: If I `print(y_train.shape)`, it returns `(4994, 9)` where 4994 is the number of samples. After the np.split, `print(len(y_train), y_train[0].shape)` returns `9 (4994, 1)` where the error throws.

Comment: @iRyanBell I added a working example to my question. Can you compare your data and see if they have correct shapes, compared to the toy data?

Comment: @thrushv89 Got it. That did the trick! I had a training validation split that was complicating the test.

Comment: How would I split this multiple `y_train` set for a validation test?